# textChange of searchbar in TabView only triggered once

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have a tab component with a search component. This component exists of a searchbar with textChange-event. The event is triggered once when the app is starting and then never again. Same code works perfectly when not part of the tabview.

The tabview (shortened):

```
<TabView id="tabview1" (selectedIndexChanged)="onSelectedIndexChanged($event)">
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'search' | L, iconSource: getIconSource('search')}">
        <Search></Search>
    </StackLayout>
</TabView>
```

The search component looks like this:

```
<Page>        
    <StackLayout>
        <SearchBar [text]="searchPhrase" (textChange)="onTextChanged($event)"></SearchBar>
    </StackLayout>
<Page>
```

onTextChanged() only prints (or rather would print) the new text to the console.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I have tried to recreate the issue but ot no avail. Everything works as expected using this test project: https://github.com/NickIliev/NS-Issues/tree/master/stackoverflow/searchTab

Comment: You can use the test project as a reference and compare your code-base with mine - do let me know if you have a stable way to reproduce the issue as the posted snippet is not enough to reproduce it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had a separate search component starting with `<page>` element. After removing it, my code worked. Sorry for providing so few code, I just didn't know what more to add.

Comment: Yep no need of `Page` in an Angular application - you can use any other layout element as a container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the `page` in my search component. After removing it, the event gets triggered as intended.